# Fork a GitHub repo into AWS CodeCommit

Tags: github, fork, branch, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to migrate a code repo from GitHub to AWS Code Commit. I need to transfer over all the active branches, which is why I want to do a fork instead of a clone. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html) is the AWS documentation for how to do it.

The git clone --mirror and git push --all commands will move all of the branches.

Comment: This isn't a fork but it successfully migrates everything.